# First and Last row, then value from beginning to the end of the year

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have a spreadsheet with group A-Z, for each group I have a stock amount for each day of the month
[Excel_Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MaKD.jpg)For each group I need to calculate the (beginning rate - end rate). I was able to separate it by group, but my code is only bringing the last stock. Would someone please help me?

```
Sub Tickets()

   Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim ColumnA As String
   Dim summaryColumA As String
   Dim Start_end_Stock As Double


   summaryColumA = 2
   Range("h1").Value = "Ticker"
   Range("I1").Value = "Yearly Change"
   Start_end_Stock = 0



        With ActiveSheet

            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         End With

    For i = 2 To LastRow

             If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then
             ColumnA = Cells(i, 1).Value


                 Start_end_Stock = Start_end_Stock + Cells(i, 3).Value
                 Range("h" & summaryColumA).Value = ColumnA
                 Range("i" & summaryColumA).Value = Start_end_Stock

                 summaryColumA = summaryColumA + 1
                 Start_end_Stock = 0


        Else


        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: this is hard to solve without your spreadsheet example but the way you have it written that if statement must be true for all to apply including the summaryColumA increment. Can you provide an example worksheet?

Comment: Hi, please see attached, thank you!